# Setting priority class and processor affinity on a process vs job object

Tags: .net, process, affinity

In .NET processor affinity and priority class for all threads and child processes can be set using `Process.ProcessorAffinity` and `Process.PriorityClass` properties. Using a [job object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it seems that the same can be set using `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_AFFINITY` and `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_PRIORITY_CLASS` flags.

So, what's the difference between setting certain limitations like the above on a job object vs a process?

**EDIT:** Once I set the limits on the job object to something lower, a low-priveleged process can still overwrite them. Does it mean the job object limits are not reinforced? How can I restrict the low-priveleged account/process from overwriting them?

**What is set:**

```
JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION jobBasicInfo = {0};
jobBasicInfo.LimitFlags = JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_AFFINITY;
jobBasicInfo.Affinity = (ULONG_PTR) (1);  // affinitize to processor 1
jobBasicInfo.LimitFlags = JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_SCHEDULING_CLASS;
jobBasicInfo.SchedulingClass = 4;         // below normal priority class
SetInformationJobObject( hJob,
      JobObjectBasicLimitInformation,
      &jobBasicInfo,
      sizeof(jobBasicInfo));
```

**How it is overriden by a low-priveleged process:**

```
Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
process.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;
// all processors mask
process.ProcessorAffinity = new IntPtr((int)Math.Pow(2, Environment.ProcessorCount) - 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one big difference and some special cases. The big difference is that limits on the job object are just that: *limits*, while setting e.g. process priority always has an immediate effect. It's not the same to *limit* the process priority to high (job object) and to *set* it to high (`PriorityClass`). The special cases arise when a process trying to give itself greater leeway than the job object allows; in which case the related API calls return success but actually do nothing, which is not the normal behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see the difference now. Do you know then why when I set the priority class to 4/BelowNormal using the job object, Process.PriorityClass still shows the priority as Normal.         JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION jobBasicInfo = {0};
jobBasicInfo.LimitFlags = JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_SCHEDULING_CLASS;
jobBasicInfo.SchedulingClass = 4;
SetInformationJobObject(hJob,JobObjectBasicLimitInformation, &jobBasicInfo, sizeof(jobBasicInfo));